# Angular JS / PHP－ can read data from database but ng-click not working

Tags: php, angularjs, crud, angularjs-ng-click

Now I can read the *PictureName* from database and show it on the browser. (Picture below: black block on the left)
[image: Picture]

And what I want to do is that, when do click on one of rows (ex: pic1), it will trigger function *change()*.

But no matter what I try, function *change()* doesn't work. What should I do to  my code? Thanks for the answers and suggestions.  :)

## read.php

```
<?php    
require 'lib.php';    
$object = new CRUD();

// table header
$data = '<table style="border-collapse:separate; border-spacing:0px 10px;">
            <tr>
                <th>No. </th>           
                <th>PictureName</th>
            </tr>';

// table body

$picturetb = $object->Read();

if (count($picturetb) > 0) {
    foreach ($picturetb as $key=>$picture) {
        $data .= '<tr ng-click="change()">
                <td>' . $key . '</td>
                <td><a>' . $picture['Picture_Name'] . '</a></td>            
            </tr>';
    }
}

$data .= '</table>';
echo $data;
?>
```

## angular.js

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
mainApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.readRecords = function () {
        $.get("ajax/read.php", {}, function (data, status) {            
            $(".addPicture").html(data);
        });
    }

    $scope.change = function () {
        console.log("do click");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you *could* use `$compile` but generally it is a very, very bad idea to inject markup this way. Why not return the key / picture as JSON:

```
$arr = [];
foreach ($picturetb as $key=>$picture) {
  $arr[] = array('key' => $key, 'picture' => $picture['Picture_Name']);
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Retrieve it like this

```
$scope.readRecords = function () {
  $.get("ajax/read.php", {}, function (data, status) {            
    $scope.data = data;
  });
}
```

In your view:

```
<table style="border-collapse:separate; border-spacing:0px 10px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No. </th>           
      <th>PictureName</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-click="change()" ng-repeat="d in data">
      <td> {{ d.key }} </td>
      <td><a> {{ d.picture }} </a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tried your suggestion. It produced the array correctly. (that
 I checked by /**console.log($scope.datadata); */)  But now it only show <thead> in my view, and <tbody> show nothing. And I think  /* <tr ng-click="change()" ng-repeat="d in data"> */  here is also correct.  I have no idea about why no show...

Comment: Do you by any chance have forgotten to connect the controller with the markup? You should have the markup wrapped in `<body ng-controller="MyController">  ... </body>` or `<div ng-controller="MyController"> ... </div>`  and place your `<table>` inside that `<div>` ...

Comment: I have used <ng-controller>.
I think that  `$scope.data = data;`  is JSON object. So I use `JSON.parse(data)` to convert text into a JavaScript object. And it still show nothing.

Comment: Afterwards, I wrap the changes in the `$scope.$apply` function.  and it work. So my problem is solved.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can still do it, if you insist on getting table from database. Here what you need to do.

-Run angular digest cycle again manually. After your table loading.

Below is the code:-

```
$timeout(function () { 
var injector = $('[ng-app]').injector();
var $compile = injector.get('$compile');
var $rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope');
$compile(this.$el)($rootScope);
$rootScope.$digest();
},0);
```

`$timeout` with time 0 will run digest cycle right.

But i'll personally suggest @davidkonrad answer.